# confused about equation Solve $x^2 – 50 = 0$

Tags: quadratics, radicals

I found the solution to above involved the following steps
$$\begin{align}
x^2-50=0&\implies x^2=50\\
&\implies\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{50}\\
&\implies x=\pm\sqrt{50}\\
&\implies x=\pm\sqrt{2\cdot 25}\\
&\implies x=\pm 5\sqrt{2}.
\end{align}$$

why is `±sqrt(2.25)` in the steps, it obviously not the square root of `50` or I am missing something my math is still baby.

Comment: It's probably meant as $2\cdot 25=50$ and not $2.25=\frac{225}{100}$

Comment: In some countries, they use $.$ to indicate multiplication.

Comment: @Arthur I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot here is used for multiplication and not as a decimal mark.Depending on context this could be because some sites which can't display math can't type $\cdot$ so they type . instead or because some countries simply use  . as multiplication